TYPO3 Problem with www and nothing used as subdomain
So I have the following problem: When I use https://www.example.com as the domain, I get the content but when I use https://example.com I get the generic TYPO3 404 error page.
I tried setting up a redirect with example.com and .* as the source path and my starting page as the target and I also tried setting up baseVariants in the site config.
It's a bit strange that my normal base is just example.com and not www.example.com but www.example.com is the one that is working while the other one just gives a 404.
I need to reliable have https://example.com and https://example.com configured to get the same page.
I use TYPO v12.4.14 on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 with an Apache Webserver and PHP 8.1
This is what I tried with the redirects. But that does not work because the regular expression has no delimiters. At least that is what I learned in the time since I made this post initially:

Edit 2:
I tried to make 2 vhosts to redirect example.com to www.example.com. Here are my config files:
File 1 example.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

File 2 example-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

Now it works for http://example.com but not for https://example.com

This is probably better suited to AskUbuntu

Remove the Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com directive from your :443 configuration and add a rule to force www. in your URI.
Your :443 configuration should look like this:
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    
    # Force www in URI 
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

The RewriteCondition checks if the host is your domain and without www. If so, then it redirects to www.example.com. Because this is server side, your 404 error should disappear.

In wich File do i need to put this and do i just put it inside the <VirtualHost *:443> block or how do i do this?

in the file where you store all other VHosts. If Apache gets a request on the 443 port it looks up all it's VHosts that are listening to 443. If there are more than 1 it looks for the ServerName and if they have a match the request goes to that VHost.
So if you get an request to example.com it enters the VHost with Port 443 and looks for ServerName example.com. In this VHost we redirect to www.example.com and so Apache looks up for the VHOst listenening to 443 and Servername www.example.com

In general that would lead to duplicate content. It's more advisable to redirect one variant to the other with your server configuration, for
example using the an redirect in the .htaccess file for apache2 or a
similar configuration for ngnix or other webservers.
Redirecting a domain not covered by one of the siteconfiguration was broken
and a corresponding fix recently merged - albeit not being released yet.
I guess, with that change a redired within ext:redirects should be possible,
see [1]
Beside that, it's not really clear what your configuration is. I would suggest to use the www.example.com variant as base url (configure a domain, not only a path).
It would be interesting how exactly you created the redirects record, with option selected and entered for all fields. The given cryptic part information does not help to eloborate what you have configured - and thus making it impossible to prober help on that exactly.

[1] 83701: [BUGFIX] Avoid NullSite in Request object setup in RedirectService https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/83701

edit1
Taken from your screenshot, you have
SOURCE_PATH.: .*
TARGET......: t3://page?uid= mixed with some path and [1] as placeholder ?

You need to use it as external url for the target (domain) along with the matching group and that you need more following settings (not tested):
SOURCE_HOST.: example.com
SOURCE_PATH.: #^(.*)#
TARGET......: https://www.example.com/$1

but only if www.example.com is the configured base for the site-config ...

I have added a picture to show what i tried with redirects in the TYPO3 backend to give some context. And i approved the spelling corrections. thx.
